# Aggregate a list column by group

Tags: r, tidyverse

Consider the following sample data

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(group = c("a", "b", "b"), val = list(1:3, 4:6, 7:12))
## A tibble: 3 × 2
#  group val      
#  <chr> <list>   
#1 a     <int [3]>
#2 b     <int [3]>
#3 b     <int [6]>
```

I would like to combine entries in column `val` based on `group`, giving the expected output

```
df_out <- tibble(group = c("a", "b"), val = list(1:3, 4:12))
```

I'm looking for a `tidyverse` solution but have been unsuccessful. For example,

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>% summarise(val = map(val, c), .groups = "drop")
```

does not concatenate `val` entries from the two `"b"` rows and instead produces a warning

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  group val      
  <chr> <list>   
1 a     <int [3]>
2 b     <int [3]>
3 b     <int [6]>
Warning message:
Returning more (or less) than 1 row per `summarise()` group was deprecated in dplyr 1.1.0.
ℹ Please use `reframe()` instead.
ℹ When switching from `summarise()` to `reframe()`, remember that `reframe()` always returns an ungrouped data frame and adjust
  accordingly.
Call `lifecycle::last_lifecycle_warnings()` to see where this warning was generated.
```

I understand the warning but I don't understand *why* "more than 1 row per `summarise()` group" is returned. Can somebody please explain and offer a solution?

I was hoping for a simple two step `group_by` + `summarise` solution (i.e. avoiding `nest`ing etc.).

---

To clarify: The numbers in `val` are not in order nor a sequence. A different set of `val` numbers for one group might be `c(1, 10, 2)` and `c(4, 7, 7)`. The expected combined output would be `c(1, 10, 2, 4, 7, 7)`. So:

```
df <- tibble(group = c("a", "b", "b"), val = list(1:3, c(1, 10, 2), c(4, 7, 7)))
df_out <- tibble(group = c("a", "b"), val = list(1:3, c(1, 10, 2, 4, 7, 7)))
```

Comment: Just `unnest` on `val` and `nest` again on `-group` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can `unlist` the value variable in the grouped data, then `list` it back

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df |> 
    group_by(group) |> 
    summarise(val = list(unlist(val))) |> 
    ungroup()

pull(df, val)

[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1]  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

Comment: The values are not always in sequence; this is just a case of my minimal sample data. So `seq` won't work. For one group you might have two sets: `c(1, 10, 2)` and `c(4, 7, 7)`. The expected output would be `c(1, 10, 2, 4, 7, 7)`.

Comment: Yes, I see that now, I corrected the answer

Comment: I think it is fine now

Comment: That's it! So straightforward. I tried `unlist` but never re-`list`ed. 3 hours wasted. Thanks for the help, much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
df %>% group_by(group) %>%  
    summarise(val = list(unlist(val)))
```

Comment: Not much different from the original answer

Comment: Thanks, that's it. So straightforward. Thanks for you help, much appreciated.